# Simple Example of a Table in SWT

Tags: java, swt

My last project I created a Singleton class and used Swing, to create my TableModel and then add the populated table to my base dialog class.

My new project however, I have to use SWT instead of Swing.  I am afraid I know little to nothing about SWT.

I want to be able to create a Table class (SelectionsTable.java).  In the table class I want to be able to create a simple table that has 4 colums and populates row values from a arraylist.

I will worry about how to pass the table to my BaseDialog class later.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really good code snippets directly from eclipse [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#table). The one that is most interesting for you should be this one: [create a table (columns, headers, lines)](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet38.java). It shows how to create a table with multiple columns, headers and lines.

Since you seem fairy familiar with java, you should be able to figure out how to use this for your purpose.

If you want to have a proper `TableViewer` with `ContentProvider`, have a look at this excellent tutorial by [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html).

Comment: Please help me understand.  In swing, you have a class that extends a tablemodel - In that class you have a getValueAt() method etc.... Then is a Dialog class you can implement a tablemodellistener then just create your JTable.  I am not understanding how SWT table works.  Would i create a table in the table class and then use a tableviewer in the dialog class?

Comment: @jkteater I don't know much about swing. Didn't the tutorial by Vogella help you? His tutorials are always really good. Moreover, you can download his code and try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

ContentProvider is like a model that provides input for TableViewer. ( Model for Table)

LabelProvider is a class that provides image and text that you will display in a Table Cell. ( similar to getValueAt() in Swing)

1. create TableViwer in your dialog
2. create TableViewerColumn (each column) for tableviewer and set LabelProvider() on TableViewerColumn. LabelProvider.getImage() LabelProvider.getText() will be called for each row object that content provider provides on this column.
3. set viewer.setContentProvider()

**This is how it works:** TableViewer first gets input from its content provider. lets say your content provider is returning List of RowObjects. For each RowObject, the label providers on each TableViewerColumn will be invoked to dispaly image and text in that particular cell location ( like colIndex, RowIndex in Swing).